# Show there are elements $x,y\in K$, s.t. $x^2+y^2=-1$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

I am trying to solve this problem :

> Let $K$ be a field not containing $\sqrt{-1}$, and $L$ be a Galois extension of $K$ containing $\sqrt{-1}$ and having Galois group $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. Show that there exists $x,y \in K$ such that $x^2+y^2=-1$.

The way to approach the solution is as $\sqrt{-1}\in L$ we can consider $K(\sqrt{-1}):K$, as the elements over there are of the form $x+y\sqrt{-1}$, we can try to look for an element whose norm is $-1$ in $K(\sqrt{-1}):K$. But what could be that element?

Comment: Write $L = K(i)(\sqrt{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha$; if $L/K$ is normal, then the relative norm of $\alpha$ must be a square in $K(i)$. If $L/K$ is cyclic, the relative norm must be a square in $K(i) \setminus K$.

Comment: " If L/K is cyclic, the relative norm must be a square in  K(i)∖K"- Why is this true? Also how this helps in checking the norm of that element is $-1$.?  I am assuming you are asking to take norm of $\alpha$ as the desired element?

Comment: In general what will be the cyclic group generator of $Gal(L:K)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = K(i)$ be the quadratic subextension, and let $\sigma$ denote an extension of the nontrivial automorphism (complex conjugation) to $L/K$. Write $L = F(\sqrt{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha \in F$. Since $L/K$ is normal we must have
$\sqrt{\alpha}^\sigma = \beta \sqrt{\alpha}$ for some $\beta \in F$. Applying $\sigma$ to this equation we get $\sqrt{\alpha}^{\sigma^2} = \beta^{1+\sigma} \sqrt{\alpha}$.
Since $L/K$ is cyclic of order $4$, we must have $\sqrt{\alpha}^{\sigma^2} = - \sqrt{\alpha}$ because $\sigma^2$ must be a nontrivial automorphism, hence $\beta^{1+\sigma} = -1$. Write $\beta = x + yi$; then
$-1 = \beta^{1+\sigma} = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: "$√\alpha^σ=β√\alpha $for some  β∈F"- Why this has to be true?

Comment: I can see $\sigma^2$ fixes $F$, so $\sqrt(\alpha)\sigma^2(\alpha^{1/2})\in F$ as it is the norm.. @franzlemmermeyer

Comment: @roydiptajit I stopped at the same spot. Obviously the square of $z=\sigma(\sqrt{\alpha})$ is in $F$. On the other hand, $z=f_1+f_2\sqrt{\alpha}$ for some $f_1,f_2\in F$. We see that 
$$z^2=(f_1^2+f_2^2\alpha)+2f_1f_2\sqrt{\alpha}.$$ We are not in characteristic two, so this is an element of $F$ if and only if $f_1f_2=0$. $f_2=0$ is impossible, so... There may be a cleaner argument :-)

Comment: Basically the same low key argument that is used when proving that no unexpected rational numbers have square roots in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen your argument is correct thanks.. I was confused by introducing norms..

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer does your answer have any connection to the point you mentioned in the comment earlier? I want to know ho0w did you came up with this?

Comment: This is Kummer theory. See 1.1.3 in https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~flemmermeyer/publ/pcft.pdf  . I had not done the calculations when I wrote the comment.