# Generator for Galois group

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, cyclic-groups

Consider the extension, $L=K(\sqrt{-1})(a^{1/2})$, for $a\in K(\sqrt{-1}),\; \sqrt{-1}\notin K$. I am trying to find an $a$ for which the extension $L:K$ becomes cyclic with cyclic group isomorphic to $Z/4Z$. What could be such an $a$?

If it is cyclic then what would be the generator of the cyclic Galois group?

Comment: Depends on $K$, surely. The first example that occurred to me was $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$, $a=e^{2\pi i/8}$ when $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta), \zeta=e^{2\pi i/16}$ is the sixteenth cyclotomic field. The Galois group $Gal(L/K)$ is then cyclic, generated by $\sigma:\zeta\mapsto\zeta^3$. Observe that $\sqrt{-2}=\zeta^2+\zeta^6$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$.

Comment: $K$ cannot be real because then complex conjugation would be an order two automorphism of $L$, but $\sqrt{-1}$ must be a fixed point of the unique automorphism of order two in the Galois group.

Comment: I've given an answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980776/show-there-are-elements-x-y-in-k-s-t-x2y2-1

Comment: Thank you sir @franzlemmermeyer

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In my example can you give a $Z/4Z$ cyclotomic extension over it? I need to prove that this type of extensions are indeed Galois..

Comment: Sorry I need to prove it cyclic

Comment: For an arbitrary choice of $a$ the extension will fail to be Galois. We want $\sigma(a)/a$ to be a square in $K(\sqrt{-1})$ without $a$ being one (reusing the idea from the other question). I think the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ over $K$ is biquadratic when [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649466/11619) may prove useful to you.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2732366/11619) may also help with the construction. With obvious corrections.